# Ant Design - searching for both key and value in a select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

If I have a user object with a display name (e.g. "John Smith") and a username (e.g. "johsmi"), how can I search for both display name and username?

This example will only search for usernames, i.e. it will find "johsmi", but not "Smith":

```
<Select
  showSearch={true}
  optionFilterProp="children"
  placeholder="Select account"
>
  {users.map(user => (
    <Select.Option value={user.name}>
      {user.displayName}                        
    </Select.Option>
  ))}
</Select>
```

I ended up adding the display name in the key attribute to make it searchable, but I wonder if it's the recommended way of doing it:

```
<Select.Option key={user.displayName} value={user.name}>
  {user.displayName}                        
</Select.Option>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Works best for me, refer this [issue](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/19143)

```
<Select
  allowClear
  showSearch
  filterOption={(inputValue, option) =>
    option.children.join('').toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase())
  }
>
  {options.map(option=> (
    <Option key={option.id}>{option.name}</Option>
  ))}
</Select>
```

Comment: Antd new version deprecate the `props`, so please use `option.children` instead of `option.props.children`. Edited the original answer.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the `filterOption` props

```
  const person = [{
    username: 'jstuart123',
    displayName: 'John Stuart'
  }]

  <Select
    showSearch
    optionFilterProp="children"
    onSearch={onSearch}
    filterOption={(input, option) =>  
      option.props.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0 
      || option.props.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
    }
  >
    {person.map(p => <Option value={p.username}>{p.displayName}</Option>)}
  </Select>
```

Exemple: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-bhabha-m5tuy

Comment: This causes an error.

Comment: @GavinThomas which error?

Comment: @rafaelncarvalho For me it's a warning: 'Return type is option instead of Option instance. Please read value directly instead of reading from `props`.' To remove the warning remove `props` from the `filterOption` chain, like this: `option.children.toLowerCase()...`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
filterOption={(input, option) =>
    option.props.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0 ||
    option.props.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
}
```

Comment: im using with vuejs, and 1 way todo it is to add data-prop to a-select-option, and getting it via option.props[data-label'].toLowerCase()...

Answer (score 2):

I also got an error when I tried the answers above. Actually I solved it like this.

```
filterOption={(input, option) =>
  option.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0 ||
  option.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
}
```

Comment: Thank you! One of those `option.value`s should be `option.label` to search both the label and value, though.

Comment: @AugDog shouldn't it be `option.children`?

Answer (score 2):

With version `4.8.2` of AntD, setting `optionFilterProp="children"` had no effect whatsoever. It's not at all clear to me what the role of that property is and what the magic string "children" stands for (e.g. does it have the usual React meaning? and if so, to whose component's children does it refer? dunno).

In my case, all I needed was `showSearch` and `filterOptions`. Moreover, my `filterOptions` had to be defined quite differently from the other answers (which didn't work for me):

```
filterOption=(input, option)=>
      option.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// add the "filterOption" props to the ant design Select component
filterOption={(input, option) =>
  // make sure that the value and key is not null 
  option.props.value !== null
  && toLower(option.props.value).includes(toLower(input))
  ||
  option.props.key !== null
  &&
  toLower(option.props.key).includes(toLower(input))
}


// here is what the "toLower" function looks like just to convert string to lower case
toLower = (value) => {
  return value.toLowerCase()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
filterOption={(input, option) =>
    option.children.join("").toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0 ||
    option.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, add more value in Option

```
 <Option
     key={index}
     value={
     agen.data.name +
     agen.no_agen +
     agen?.data?.city_area_survey?.keywords
     }
```